# How do I clone vector?

Tags: c++, networking

I am using vector as an input buffer...

```
recv = read(m_fd, &m_vbuffer[totalRecv], SIZE_OF_BUFFER);
```

After it reads all data from the input buffer then it will put the data inside of the vector into the thread pool.

So I was trying to do clone the vector. I think I cannot just pass the pointer to the vector because of the new packets coming in and it overwrites the data inside of the vector.

However, I could not find a way to clone the vector. Please provide me a proper way to handle this. Also I will be very appreciated if you guys point out any problems using vectors as input buffer or tutorials related to this...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can easily copy a vector using its copy constructor:

```
vector<T> the_copy(the_original); // or
vector<T> the_copy = the_original;
```

Comment: +1, but maybe better not call it copy in case he does `#include <algorith>` and `using namespace std`.

Answer (score 2):

At the first, you may have to call recv with `&m_vbuffer[0]`.
About cloning of vector, use copy().

```
#include <algorithm>
...

vector<char> m_vcopy;
m_vcopy.reserve(m_vbuffer.size());
copy(m_vbuffer.begin(), m_vbuffer.end(), m_vcopy.begin());
```

However, note that the element should not be reference. :)

Comment: Also you will find `vector::swap()` to be more efficient since it avoids the copy entirely.

Comment: @Nemo: When the whole point is to copy (aka clone), avoiding the copy should be the least of your worries. You'll also find the empty statement `;` to be more efficient, but it won't do what you want.

Comment: My point is that the user is asking the wrong question.  The last thing you want to do is to make yet another copy of every byte arriving from the network.  Also I assume he is calling `recv` in a loop (else his code is wrong) which is why he is using `&m_buffer[totalRecv]` instead of `m_buffer[0]`.  It's the `SIZE_OF_BUFFER` argument that is wrong; it should be `m_buffer.size() - totalRecv`

Answer (score 0):

As Nemo points out, you might want to consider whether you really need a copy of the vector.  Can you get away with transferring the contents using `std::swap` or `std::move` (if using C++0x)?